# Espaço indesejado de 1px no Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css

No meu site, abaixo do rodapé existe um espaço de `1px` que só ocorre no Internet Explorer.
No meu caso, estou a usar o **IE-10**. O rodapé tem posicionamento fixo, eu inseri ele fora do *container* do site, e coloquei-o de volta definindo uma margem inferior negativa ao *container*.

```css
.MASTER {
    width:1169px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /*margin-bottom:-228px;*/
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -228px;
}
.MT_SEM_SOMBRAS {
    width:1155px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#fixer {
    width:1155px;
    height:228px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#FF0;
}
#push {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1155px;
    height:228px;
}
```

```html
<div id="MASTER">
    <div id="MT_SEM_SOMBRAS">
        Conteúdo do site
    </div>
</div>

<div id="fixer"> <!--este na verdade é o rodapé-->
    conteúdo com margem negativa
</div>
```

Comment: Eu quero remover esse espaço indesejado no ie. No Dreamweaver, ele também não aparece

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o problema, poderia fornecer um exemplo no jsfiddle?

Comment: acredito que no jsfiddle não reproduziria o problema, uma vez que ocorre apenas no internet explorer.

Comment: estou usando a técnica sticky footer.

Comment: @Harison jsfiddle não é um browser, é um ambiente pra você reproduzir o teu problema, então você envia o link pra gente e então iremos abrir no InternetExplorer.

Comment: http://hfoliveira.com.br/MAQUES/TESTE_RODAPE.html

Comment: A margem negativa ainda aí está ?

Comment: Ainda permanece.

Comment: Tentou fazer um clear:both no rodapé?

Comment: A pergunta carece de informações. Inviável reproduzir.

Comment: pergunta em discussão no meta http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4488/usu%C3%A1rio-com-multiplas-perguntas-similares

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar [CSS Hack](http://www.impressivewebs.com/ie10-css-hacks/) pra isso, exemplo:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) { 
   // apenas IE 10
   // aqui tu coloca a classe com a margin negativo pro IE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicionar ao CSS

```
body{
        margin:0 0 0 0;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
    }
```

Este código tem o objectivo de reforçar que não pretendemos espaço entre o body e o conteúdo.

Exemplo.:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
        <title>Documento sem título</title>
        <style>
            body{
                margin:0 0 0 0;
                padding: 0 0 0 0;
            }
            #MASTER {
                width:1169px;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #MT_SEM_SOMBRAS {
                width:1155px;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                height:100%;
            }
            #fixer {
                clear:both;
                width:1155px;
                height:228px;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                background-color:#FF0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="MASTER">
            <div id="MT_SEM_SOMBRAS">
                Conteúdo do site

            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="fixer"> <!--este na verdade é o rodapé-->
                conteúdo com margem negativa
        </div> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seria bom se pudesse explicar pq esse código funciona ou qual é finalidade. :)

Comment: Não funcionou...

Comment: Se calhar não percebi bem o constrangimento. O que percebi foi que entre o rodapé e o bottom do body existia 1px em branco no iexplorer 10

Comment: É isso mesmo @TiagoGomes, conseguiu visualizar o problema?

Comment: Editei a resposta para colocar o html. Com este código continua a ter 1px entre o rodapé e o body?