# Que espaço desconhecido é este?

Tags: html, css

Site: http://hfoliveira.com.br/MAQUES/CONT.html

Aqui o problema demonstrado: imageshack.com/a/img909/690/AjeiLg.png

A outra pergunta fui eu quem postei, postei novamente pois ainda não tive uma resposta que solucionasse o problema.

Meu problema só ocorre no internet explorer, destaquei a div inferior em vermelho para visualização. Ao redimensionar a janela diminuindo seu tamanho, há um espaço de aprox. 1px de tamanho, um espaço em branco desconhecido. O que pode ser isso?

html:

```
<div class="MASTER">

<div class="MT_SEM_SOMBRAS">

<!-- ... o conteúdo do site vai aqui... -->

<div id="push">
</div>

</div>
<!--FIM MT SEM SOMBRAS-->

</div>
<!--FIM MASTER-->
```

Css:

Div push (a que está em vermelho):

```
#push {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:1155px;
height:227px;
            background-color:#F00;
}
```

Container 1 do site:

```
.MASTER {
    width:1169px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
/*html .MASTER {
height: 100%;  hack para IE6 que trata height como min-height   
}*/
```

Container 2 do site:

```
.MT_SEM_SOMBRAS {
width:1155px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: Por favor poste seu código HTML e CSS para que possamos te ajudar a entender e resolver.

Comment: no seu arquivo Estilo.css, a propriedade #push, altere o height para 235px e veja se isso pode lhe ajudar

Comment: O espaço ocorre após a div que está em vermelho, ao redimensionar apenas a altura. Só ocorre no internet explorer.

Comment: Harison, tente colocar no seu código CSS a tag * { box-sizing: border-box }

Comment: Não funcionou. @ErickGallani

Comment: Há no meu código divs vazias de conteúdo, que tem apenas uma imagem de background. Pode ser isso?

Comment: Possível duplicada de [Espaço indesejado de 1px no Internet Explorer](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88401/espa%c3%a7o-indesejado-de-1px-no-internet-explorer)

Comment: pergunta em discussão no meta http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4488/usu%C3%A1rio-com-multiplas-perguntas-similares

Answer (score 0):

Na realidade, não é um espaço adicionado que aparece ali. Observe que alterando o background-color da classe MASTER, você nota que a sua div é que subiu.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como dica sugiro que você use na sua div.push estas propriedades:

```
float: left;
margin-top: 8px;
```

Testei aqui e deu certo. Veja ai se ajuda.

Comment: Infelizmente não deu certo.