# Espaço indesejado ao adicionar uma Google Font

Tags: css, font

Ao utilizar a fonte *Source Sans Pro* do *Google Font*, notei que logo após o rodapé aparece um espaçamento de 1px, no final do *document* se o mesmo for carregado no *Internet Explorer* (versão 10).

**Como posso manter a utilização dessa fonte e corrigir o problema?**

Trecho de código:

```css
@import url(https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Source+Sans+Pro);
 .TÍTULOS_1 {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-indent: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding-left: 19px;
}
.SUBTÍTULOS {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-indent: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #F00;
  padding-bottom: 19px;
  padding-left: 19px;
}
```

```html
<div id="MASTER">
  <div id="MT">
    Conteúdo principal aqui
    <div>
      <p class="TÍTULOS_1" id="PRIMEIRO_TÍTULOS_1">Telefone:</p>
      <p class="SUBTÍTULOS">12345678</p>
      <p class="TÍTULOS_1">E-mail:</p>
      <p class="SUBTÍTULOS">endereço@bol.com.br</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="FIXER">
    Rodapé fixado no bottom da página aqui.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Posta o trecho de HTML e CSS com o problema e o link da fonte para podermos ajudá-lo.

Comment: @Harison, você tem varias perguntas perguntando a respeito de "1px ao final da pagina". Aconselho que leia sobre CSS Resets e sobre o Normalize, eles são uteis para tornar o desenvolvimento cross-browser igualitário e podem te auxiliar na maioria dessas perguntas. Links para informações dos itens acima: http://tableless.com.br/css-reset/ e https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css respectivamente.

Comment: pergunta em discussão no meta http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4488/usu%C3%A1rio-com-multiplas-perguntas-similares

Comment: Similar: [Espaço indesejado de 1px no Internet Explorer](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/88401/espa%c3%a7o-indesejado-de-1px-no-internet-explorer)